# For an SVM with a precomputed Gram matrix, do the kernels need to be normalized to between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, kernel-methods

I'm using Scikit-Learn for text classification in Python. My classifier is currently making false predictions for everything (I was fooled for a while because it reported "75% accuracy" when 75% of the labels were false), so I'm trying to figure out what's wrong.

Currently, I'm doing `SVC(kernel='precomputed')` and computing the Gram matrix manually before passing it to `fit()` and `predict()`. The entry $G_{ij}$ of the Gram matrix is the kernel $K(d_i, d_j)$, where K denotes the kernel function and d_i is the ith document.

For my kernel function, the Gram matrix entries are not normalized, i.e. some are greater than 1. Do I need to apply kernel normalization

```
$$
K'(d_i, d_j) = \frac{K(d_i, d_j)}{\sqrt{K(d_i, d_i) \times K(d_j, d_j)}}
$$
```

to get it between 0 and 1? Or do SVMs not care?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not need to pre-scale the vectors. An SVM modelling process should be invariant to linear transforms of the data.

Comment: Note: It is not the vectors itself but the inner products. Also I am not sure if dividing by that sqrt expression qualifies as linear.

Comment: My mistake. I'm still fairly sure you don't need to normalize the Gram matrix, though, since it won't change the shape or inter-relations of the data described.

Comment: OK, thanks for the information. Do you know why `linear_kernel` is normalized then? (It returns cosine similarities, and 0 < cos theta < 1)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library in question, but I'd imagine that kind of normalization is used for the same reason you'd use a L1 or L2 normalization. The result is more canonical, less ambiguous, and numerically simpler. These are data qualities - the yes/no functional output is the same in any of these cases.

Comment: SVMs surely are affected by the normalizing of the data in terms of speed and maybe performance.